# Why isn't DragDrop working?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to do something very simple, yet it's proving to be the most complicated thing I have ever done.
        private void dropper_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            /// TODO: Get the data and do something with it.

```
        // DEBUG ONLY:
        MessageBox.Show("Dropped.");
        dropper.BackColor = detector.BackColor;

    }
```

Doesn't work. Does not print to console. Does now show messagebox. Does not change background color.

Comment: is the handler hooked up?  does the widget (whatever it is you are working with) have AllowDrop true?

Comment: Is the method being invoked when firing the drag drop event? Did you put any break points?

Comment: @Plutonix The handler is definitely hooked up, and the Panel control does indeed have AllowDrop set to true. Also, I have tried using other controls like TextBox and Button and PictureBox - same result.

Comment: how/where/who is initiating the DragDrop?

Comment: @AnupSharma I just tried with breakpoints, and nothing's being hit.

Comment: @Plutonix `dropper`, which is a Panel control, receives the drop. I am dropping plain text and links from IE (browser) onto the Panel control (dropper).

Comment: Try re hooking the event with the handler

Comment: @AnupSharma Will do that now.

Comment: If that also doesn't work then delete it and do it manually using droper.dragdrop+=(s,o)=>{...};

Comment: @AnupSharma Finally! It works! Your first suggestion fixed it. I re-hooked the event in Form1.Designer.cs after Clean Solution and Rebuild All and it's now working as expected. Thank you :-) I'll also note for future readers, that I did try other suggestions from other answers on this site where they say that running the app with admin privileges will make it work. I tried that but it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Your snippet is quite incapable to reproducing the problem.  It is however doing something very, very dangerous.  Starting a modal message loop in a D+D event handler has a knack for causing very hard to diagnose mishaps.

Starting with the drag source, it is still hung in its DoDragDrop() method call and will go catatonic while the message box is displayed.  This is unhealthy.  The message loop pumped by the D+D plumbing is roughly equivalent to calling the infamous DoEvents() method when it is called at an inappropriate time.  The re-entrancy problems that can cause are pretty hard to reason through, it does not assume any input events will ever reach it.  But it does now.

You need to make sure that the message box is displayed *after* the D+D completes.  Like this:

```
    private void dropper_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show("Yadayada")));
    }
```

And *never* do this to debug anything, you have a debugger for that.  Set a breakpoint.

Also pay attention to the content of the Output window.  There might be a "First chance exception" notification there.  The D+D event handlers swallow exceptions without a peep.  Debug that with Debug > Exceptions > tick the Thrown checkbox for CLR exceptions.